# Pinterest API https://api.pinterest.com/v1/me/ returns "authorization failed"

Tags: api, pinterest

I successfully passed oauth part, got access token successfully. I need to get user profile by calling https://api.pinterest.com/v1/me/?access_token='token'. But it returned to me:

```
{  
   "status":"failure",
   "code":3,
   "host":"coreapp-devplatform-devapi-184",
   "generated_at":"Wed, 30 Sep 2015 01:57:50 +0000",
   "message":"Authorization failed.",
   "data":null
}
```

It works for app creator, but not for collaborator or tester. What am I missing?

Comment: Nothing. Unfortunately, it is a known issue that Pinterest is fixing.

Comment: Thank you! Good to know it's a known issue. Will wait for it getting fixed.

Comment: My tests show that it is working for collaborators or testers now, too. You may try again now.

Answer (score 1):

Just verified Pinterest has fixed the issue. Now it works for collaborators or testers. Make sure the collaborators or testers follow the app creator's Pinterest account.